# utAsp. Net How to get the value of input control and keep it there until chosen otherwise, even after postback?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, textinput

I'm using two input controls to allow the user to choose dates "from and to" that are used to load the Gridview. However, after a postback the input looses it's entered value. What is the best way to persist the value and show these dates on the page?
thx for the help!
This is the code for the to date input control (aspx)

```
    <tr>
    <td class="style2">To Date:</td>
    <td class="style3"><input id="toDate" name="toDate" type="text" size="12"         autopostback="true" onchange="ToDate_TextChanged"
    onfocus="javascript:if(this.value=='dd/mm/yyyy'){this.value=''};vDateType='3'"         onkeyup="DateFormat(this,this.value,event,false,'3')" 
    onblur="DateFormat(this,this.value,event,true,'3')" value=""  />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="toDateHiddenField" Value="" runat="server" />
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I can't access the control from codebehind (c#) to check the value of it, therefore i've added the hiddenfield, still no luck.

Comment: Are you using viewstate, or are you resetting the value somewhere in your page load?  You may need to wrap a place you are setting their initial value in an if (!IsPostback) { } block

Comment: Post some code to see if we can help you further.

Comment: i've posted part of the code... thx!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have runat server on your input.  Then you can enable viewstate for it or access it in code behind